# Freeing an interfaced object with ARC vs without - Delphi

Tags: delphi, automatic-ref-counting, delphi-xe5

I'm working on a project where I have a interfaced TRectangle like this:

```
IBoardShape = interface(IInterface)
  function GetColor: integer;
  procedure SetColor(const aColor: integer);
  property Color: integer read GetColor write SetColor;
end;

TGameRectangle = class(TRectangle, IBoardShape)
private
  FColor: integer;
  procedure SetColor(const aColor: integer);
  function GetColor: integer;
  property Color: integer read GetColor write SetColor;
protected
  {$IFNDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  [Volatile] FRefCount: Integer;
  {$ENDIF}
  function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
  function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
end;
```

`_AddRef` and `_Release` are the same as in `InterfacedObject`:

```
function TGameRectangle._AddRef: Integer;
begin
{$IFNDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  Result := AtomicIncrement(FRefCount);
{$ELSE}
  Result := __ObjAddRef;
{$ENDIF}
end;

function TGameRectangle._Release: Integer;
begin
{$IFNDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  Result := AtomicDecrement(FRefCount);
  if Result = 0 then
    Destroy;
{$ELSE}
  Result := __ObjRelease;
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

To create a rectangle I do this:

```
var  
  lRect: TGameRectangle;
begin
  lRect := TGameRectangle.Create(self);
  lRect.Parent := Layout1;
  lRect.Align := TAlignLayout.alClient;
  FIntObj := lRect as IBoardShape;
```

Later I free it by setting the `FIntObj` to `nil`. On Windows when I follow`_Release` the reference count is 1 and the count gets decremented and the object gets freed. When running on Android the reference count is 5 when I enter into `_Release` (the reference count is shown inside `__ObjRelease`). Since the reference count is still high the object doesn't free.

I've recreated this in a very simple demo using basically just the code I've posted here. Could someone explain what's different in ARC that's causing the reference count to be so high?

Comment: While working with ARC **every** reference to the instance increases the RefCount. You are passing an Owner and a Parent and both of them hold at **minimum** one reference to that instance. Plus your interface reference you have minimum 3 - but there are certainly more references that are caused by Owner and Parent.

Comment: @SirRufo ... unless you use a `[weak]` reference, which is needed e.g. for circular references. See [Marco's article](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/automatic_reference_counting_for_delphi.html). IMHO such breaking change of the Delphi's memory model was one of the worst ideas ever.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Delphi is way too much afraid of changes, especially breaking changes. I yearn for the advent of ARC for the desktop compiler. There is nothing wrong with using the `[weak]` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this is simply unnecessary under ARC because ARC already counts references and controls lifetime.

Under ARC you can, and should, rely on the `IInterface` implementation from the base class.

Under ARC your code should look like this:

```
TGameRectangle = class(TRectangle, IBoardShape)
private
  FColor: integer;
  procedure SetColor(const aColor: integer);
  function GetColor: integer;
  property Color: integer read GetColor write SetColor;
end;
```

---

Your bigger problem is that your code can never work on non-ARC platforms. That's because you have a `TComponent` descendent that is owned. As such the owner holds a reference to the rectangle object and will attempt to destroy when it is destroyed. In addition to that, your interface reference counting also assumes ownership. As a rule, objects need to have exactly one owner. Your design gives them two.

You should, on non-ARC platforms, only manage the lifetime through interface reference counting if the object has no owner. I discussed this in more detail in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770260/freeing-interfaced-object-that-descends-from-a-trectangle/21775037#21775037) to your previous question.

Comment: Wouldn't just passing `nil` as `AOwner` for the constructor of `TRectangle` solve that?

Comment: @Günther the Beautiful Indeed it would. But he doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your help, both in this answer and the other one. I tried passing in nil but I got an exception as soon as the method that created the object was exited (inside _IntfCopy in System). I don't think I'm going to try to do that (like you said it feels like going against a design by using my own), I'll just keep track of the object.